# ActiveMQ SSL Connection KeyStore and TrustStore Type

Tags: java, ssl, jms, activemq-classic

The ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory has methods setTrustStoreType(String type) and setKeyStoreType(String type).

From the documentation http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.13.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.html#setKeyStoreType(java.lang.String)

I see that the KeyStore and TrustStore files are supposed to be in jks format, but my question is, what are the different types I could be setting for these?

Are there different types that are supported by ActiveMQ? I cannot find documentation listing supported types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are defined in the [Standard Names documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore) from Oracle. By default, the type is jks.

Comment: No, sorry, but I commented how I could.